# Андроид демонстрация обновления

Tags: java, android, мобильная-разработка

Необходимо, чтобы после обновления на устройстве при первом входе открывался некий фрагмент, демонстрирующий "Что нового в приложении", так вот как можно отследить то, что пользователь впервые запустил приложение после обновления?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `SharedPreferences` и `BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE`
Проверяйте после запуска, какая у вас версия кода. Если новая то открывайте демонстрационный фрагмент и сохраняйте `BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE` в `SharedPreferences`

Comment: Я в принципе так и собирался, но надежду таил, что есть способ поизящнее